# How to check if tuple has any item?

Tags: c#, tuples

I have the following tuple:

```
Tuple <string, string> UHRSCredentals;

UHRSCredentals = new Tuple<string, string>(UserNameLine.Split('\t')[1], PasswordLine.Split('\t')[1]);
```

How do I check if UHRSCredentals has any item other than doing this?

```
if (UHRSCredentals.Item1 != "" && UHRSCredentals.Item2 !="")
```

Comment: What does it mean to "have any item"? If it means "have non-empty strings" then I'm not sure you can do anything other than what you're already doing. Why do you think or feel you need to?

Comment: A [`Tuple<t1,t2>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx) is a class, so a reference type. You can use `UHRSCredentals!=null`. Apart from that it depends on your logic if it is a valid item, since you store a username and a password even empty strings could be valid.

Comment: I guess you want to check for an erroneous case. What can possibly go wrong when you create your tuple?

Comment: If you want to check if a string is empty, there's also the [String.IsNullOrEmpty method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx) in C#.

Comment: Tuples in C# are declared like `(string str1, string str2) UHRSCredentals`

Answer (score 3):

You could write a simple extension method:

```
public static class TupleExtensions
{
    public static bool HasValue(this Tuple<string, string> tuple)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tuple?.Item1) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tuple?.Item2);
    }
}

var UHRSCredentals = Tuple.Create(UserNameLine.Split('\t')[1], PasswordLine.Split('\t')[1]);
bool hasValue = UHRSCredentals.HasValue(); // True!
```

But maybe you should consider a small class to more clearly represent and encapsulate your intentions:

```
class UsernamePasswordPair
{
    public string Username { get; private set; }
    public string Password { get; private set; }
    public bool HasValue { get; private set; }

    public static UsernamePasswordPair Create(string usernameLine, string passwordLine)
    {
        UsernamePasswordPair pair = new UsernamePasswordPair();
        pair.Username = usernameLine?.Split('\t')[1];
        pair.Password = passwordLine?.Split('\t')[1];
        pair.HasValue = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(pair.Username) 
                && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(pair.Password);
        return pair;
    }
}

UsernamePasswordPair p1 = UsernamePasswordPair.Create(UserNameLine, PasswordLine);
bool hasValue = p1.HasValue; // True!
```